# "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure" even though the procedure is there

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

So I'm learning how to use Selenium to test a project and I want to compare the value in stored procedure with the inputs. I have check the stored procedure (XE_SEARCH) and don't know what is wrong with it that make me have this error. I tried using another procedure (CM_XE_Search, this is an old one we're no longer use it) in the same database and it worked fine. I've included pics so you can look at the problem better.Can someone help me with this? Thank you very much.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRieQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3YLf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKill.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcnzX.png)

Here is the code

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Linq;
using Group11.XE.Test.XEDTO;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Threading;
using Group11.XE.Test.Helper;


namespace Group11.XE.Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class CreateXE : Load
    {

        public CreateXE()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            homeURL = "http://localhost:4200";

        }

        [TestMethod]
        [DataRow("Exciter", "Đen", 2, "Ex 150", "71C4-45677", 42000000, 2, "Xe vua mua", 135,"Yamaha", 2019)]
        public void Create_XE_With_OK_Status(String Name, String Color, int Seats, String Model, String License, int Price, int Consumption, String Notes, int Mspeed, String Manufacturer, int Manufacture_year)
        {
            String Code = (new Random().Next(1, 99999999)).ToString();


            Login();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(homeURL + "/app/admin/xe-group11-add");
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.Name("xE_CODE")));
            Thread.Sleep(8000);

            //Act;
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_CODE")).SendKeys(Code);
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_NAME")).SendKeys(Name);
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_COLOR")).SendKeys(Color);
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_SEATS")).SendKeys(Seats.ToString());
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_MODEL")).SendKeys(Model);
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_LICENSE_PLATE")).SendKeys(License);
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_PRICE")).SendKeys(Price.ToString());
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_CONSUMPTION")).SendKeys(Consumption.ToString());
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_NOTES")).SendKeys(Notes);
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_MAX_SPEED")).SendKeys(Mspeed.ToString());
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_MANUFACTURER")).SendKeys(Manufacturer);
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_MANUFACTURE_YEAR")).SendKeys(Manufacture_year.ToString());
            //driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_STATUS")).SendKeys(Status);

            IWebElement comboBox = driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_STATUS"));
            SelectElement selectedValue = new SelectElement(comboBox);
            selectedValue.SelectByIndex(0);
            String Status = selectedValue.ToString();

            //get value of select element



            IWebElement ele = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/app-root/ng-component/div/div/div[2]/ng-component/form/ul/li[1]"));
            IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);


            //Check with value of DB
            //CM_XE_DTO input = new CM_XE_DTO(Code, Name, Origin);
            XE_DTO finalRow = DataProvider.Instance.GetData<XE_DTO>("XE_SEARCH", new { XE_CODE = Code, XE_Name = Name, XE_COLOR = Color, XE_SEATS = Seats, XE_MODEL = Model, XE_LICENSE_PLATE = License, XE_PRICE = Price, XE_CONSUMPTION = Consumption, XE_NOTES = Notes, XE_MAX_SPEED = Mspeed, XE_MANUFACTURER = Manufacturer, XE_MANUFACTURE_YEAR = Manufacture_year, XE_STATUS = Status }).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(Code, finalRow.XE_CODE);
            Assert.AreEqual(Name, finalRow.XE_NAME);
            Assert.AreEqual(Color, finalRow.XE_COLOR);
            Assert.AreEqual(Seats, finalRow.XE_SEATS);
            Assert.AreEqual(Model, finalRow.XE_MODEL);
            Assert.AreEqual(License, finalRow.XE_LICENSE_PLATE);
            Assert.AreEqual(Price, finalRow.XE_PRICE);
            Assert.AreEqual(Consumption, finalRow.XE_CONSUMPTION);
            Assert.AreEqual(Notes, finalRow.XE_NOTES);
            Assert.AreEqual(Mspeed, finalRow.XE_MAX_SPEED);
            Assert.AreEqual(Manufacturer, finalRow.XE_MANUFACTURER);
            Assert.AreEqual(Manufacture_year, finalRow.XE_MANUFACTURE_YEAR);
            Assert.AreEqual(Status, finalRow.XE_STATUS);

            driver.Close();

        }
}
```

Data Provider

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Dapper;
using Group11.XE.Test.Helper.DTO;

namespace Group11.XE.Test.Helper
{
    class DataProvider
    {
        private static DataProvider instance;

        private DataProvider() { }
        internal static DataProvider Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new DataProvider();
                }
                return instance;
            }

            private set => instance = value;
        }//Cap Instance
        string conection = "Server=tcp:quanlitaisan.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=QuanLiTaiSan;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=QLTS_Dev;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";



        private List<ProcedureParamInfo> GetParamInfos(IDbConnection conn, string procedureName)
        {
            var rr = conn.Query<ProcedureParamInfo>($"select PARAMETER_NAME, PARAMETER_MODE, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH from information_schema.parameters where specific_name = '{procedureName}'");
            return rr.ToList();
        }

        public List<T> GetData<T>(string procedureName, object parameter)
        {
            List<T> result;

            using (IDbConnection con = new SqlConnection(conection))
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    con.Open();

                var paramsInfo = GetParamInfos(con, procedureName);

                DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();

                var properties = parameter.GetType().GetProperties();

                foreach (var param in paramsInfo)
                {
                    var property = properties // nsx_code == nsx_code
                                    .Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == param.PARAMETER_NAME.Replace("@", "").ToLower())
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
                    if (property == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    var debug1 = property.GetValue(parameter);
                    parameters.Add(param.PARAMETER_NAME, property.GetValue(parameter));
                }

                result = con.Query<T>(procedureName, parameters, null, true, null, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to call any other procedure? and make sure that you are hitting the right database

Comment: Yes sir. It seems I can call CM_XE_ related procedure and can not call XE_ related procedure so I think there is something wrong with the procedure then. These 2 are in the same database so I think I'm not hitting wrong database.

Comment: there is space in `XE_ related` name

Comment: No sir. I mean I can call CM_XE_Insert , CM_XE_Search, CM_XE_Update, ... These are old procedures that I no longer use. And I can't call XE_SEARCH, XE_UPDATE, XE_INSERT , ... These are the ones that I'm using to test now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are connecting to the correct database?

Comment: Yes sir. I tried calling another stored procedure within the same database and It could find that stored procedure. I think It might be the permissions to the stored procedure that are causing this error but I don't know how to check.

Comment: you need to change the connection string so that it connects to the correct db